# How to compute the uncertainty of $C$ given the uncertainty of $A$ and $B$, if $A = BC$?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Assuming $A = B \cdot C$ is an equation with certain physics meaning.

We have already known the uncertainty($\sigma$) of $A$ is $30$%, the uncertainty of $B$ is $100$%. How to compute the uncertainty of variable $C$. Assuming  $A$ and $B$ are independent.

I read a thesis related to this question which had derived the uncertainty of $C$ is $104$%. I can't figure out how to estimate it?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [propagation of uncertainty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty) for the example with the product (and it is the same for a ratio.

$$\left(\frac{\sigma_f}{f}\right)^2 \approx \left(\frac{\sigma_a}{a} \right)^2 + \left(\frac{\sigma_b}{b}\right)^2 + 2\left(\frac{\sigma_a}{a}\right)\left(\frac{\sigma_b}{b}\right)\rho_{ab}$$

So, neglecting the cross term, $$\sqrt{100^2+30^2}=\sqrt{10900}\approx 104.4$$